# numpy.concatenate float64(101,1) and float64(101,)

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I'm a MatLab user who recently converted to python. I am running a for loop that cuts a longer signal into individual trials, normalizes them to 100% trial and then would like to have the trials listed horizontally in a single variable. My code is

```
RHipFE=np.empty([101, 1])

newlength = 101

for i in range(0,len(R0X)-1,2):
    iHipFE=redataf.RHipFE[R0X[i]:R0X[i+1]]
    x=np.arange(0,len(iHipFE),1)
    new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), newlength)
    iHipFEn = interpolate.interp1d(x, iHipFE)(new_x)
    RHipFE=np.concatenate((RHipFE,iHipFEn),axis=1)
```

When I run this, I get the error "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions". Which I assume is because RHipFE is (101,1) while iHipFEn is (101,). Is the best solution to make iHipFEn (101,1)? If so, how does one do this in the above for loop?

Comment: Might be of use: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: In MATLAB all matrices are 2d or larger.  In `numpy` they can be 1d (or even 0d).  `a[:,None]` is the most idiomatic way of adding trailing dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's faster to collect arrays in a list, and use some form of concatenate once.  List `append` is faster than `concatenate`:

```
In [51]: alist = []
In [52]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     alist.append(np.arange(i,i+5))
    ...:     
In [53]: alist
Out[53]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]
```

Various ways of joining

```
In [54]: np.vstack(alist)  
Out[54]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
In [55]: np.column_stack(alist)  
Out[55]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [56]: np.stack(alist, axis=1)
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [57]: np.array(alist)
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Internally, `vstack`, `column_stack`, `stack` expand the dimension of the components, and concatenate on the appropriate axis:

```
In [58]: np.concatenate([l[:,None] for l in alist],axis=1)
Out[58]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I decided to append the lists instead of concatenating. I then used vstack to stack them all into an array and transposed it.